# Which notes can you double in a IV6 chord built on raised ^6?

Tags: voice-leading

In the progression from IV6 to V65 in minor you need to raise both scale degree 6 and 7 but what notes can you double in the IV6 chord? Could the raised note be doubled in the upper parts or is this avoided? What is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the subdominant 36-chord by IV6 (and not the sixte ajoutée). I also suppose you mean the raised third in the IV6 chord. Then you can double *any* note, but it traditionally considered preferable not to double the third (which is in the bass), unless you need to to avoid parallels or bad intervals (which usually happens when you have chains of 6-chords. Thus you are not allowed to double leading tones.

So in this case you could say that it is somewhat nescessary to double the third (unless you want to allow for jumps in voices), as if you double a note in a different octave, you get:

A doubled root, so one root has to ascend into the root of the dominant. Thus the fifth of the subdominant has to fall into the third of the dominant, which is a leading tone and must not be doubled.

Or a doubled fifth, one of which has to fall into the third of the dominant, which is again not allowed.

If you double one note in the same octave you could have for the subdominant the fifth once and above the root twice. This could then go into fifth, seventh and root of the dominant, but this will not sound very elegant, as all voices move upwards.